# Buildozer Spec File Requirement Libraries

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I read that when we building a program with Buildozer, we add all the libraries instead of pure python libraries in the program to buildozer.spec file. I wonder that should I add the dependencies for a library.

For example;

I use "pipdeptree" library to see all the dependencies for a library. I use "Pyrebase" library in my program and those are dependencies for "Pyrebase"

```
Pyrebase==3.0.27
  - gcloud [required: ==0.17.0, installed: 0.17.0]
    - googleapis-common-protos [required: Any, installed: 1.56.3]
      - protobuf [required: >=3.15.0,<5.0.0dev, installed: 4.21.2]
    - httplib2 [required: >=0.9.1, installed: 0.20.4]
      - pyparsing [required: >=2.4.2,<4,!=3.0.3,!=3.0.2,!=3.0.1,!=3.0.0, installed: 3.0.7]
    - oauth2client [required: >=2.0.1, installed: 3.0.0]
      - httplib2 [required: >=0.9.1, installed: 0.20.4]
        - pyparsing [required: >=2.4.2,<4,!=3.0.3,!=3.0.2,!=3.0.1,!=3.0.0, installed: 3.0.7]
      - pyasn1 [required: >=0.1.7, installed: 0.4.8]
      - pyasn1-modules [required: >=0.0.5, installed: 0.2.8]
        - pyasn1 [required: >=0.4.6,<0.5.0, installed: 0.4.8]
      - rsa [required: >=3.1.4, installed: 4.8]
        - pyasn1 [required: >=0.1.3, installed: 0.4.8]
      - six [required: >=1.6.1, installed: 1.16.0]
    - protobuf [required: >=3.0.0b2,!=3.0.0.b2.post1, installed: 4.21.2]
    - six [required: Any, installed: 1.16.0]
  - oauth2client [required: ==3.0.0, installed: 3.0.0]
    - httplib2 [required: >=0.9.1, installed: 0.20.4]
      - pyparsing [required: >=2.4.2,<4,!=3.0.3,!=3.0.2,!=3.0.1,!=3.0.0, installed: 3.0.7]
    - pyasn1 [required: >=0.1.7, installed: 0.4.8]
    - pyasn1-modules [required: >=0.0.5, installed: 0.2.8]
      - pyasn1 [required: >=0.4.6,<0.5.0, installed: 0.4.8]
    - rsa [required: >=3.1.4, installed: 4.8]
      - pyasn1 [required: >=0.1.3, installed: 0.4.8]
    - six [required: >=1.6.1, installed: 1.16.0]
  - pycryptodome [required: ==3.4.3, installed: 3.4.3]
  - python-jwt [required: ==2.0.1, installed: 2.0.1]
    - jws [required: >=0.1.3, installed: 0.1.3]
  - requests [required: ==2.11.1, installed: 2.11.1]
  - requests-toolbelt [required: ==0.7.0, installed: 0.7.0]
    - requests [required: >=2.0.1,<3.0.0, installed: 2.11.1]
```

Should I add those? such as;

```
# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3, kivy, pyrebase, gcloud, oauth2client, requests, requests-toolbelt, pycryptodome
```

Thanks!